# JNI Unsupported argument type java.lang.StringBuilder

Tags: java, c++, vb.net

I am completely new to JNI. I am trying to call a scanner dll from my java application. I have the vb.net code calling this dll and it is working fine. When i call this function from my java code i got this error "Unsupported argument type java.lang.StringBuilder".

vb.net

```
<DllImport("some32.DLL")> _
    Public Shared Function myCFunction(ByVal param1 As StringBuilder, ByRef param2 As Integer, ByRef param3 As Integer) As Integer
    End Function
```

In Java,

```
  StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder(255);
    int p1 = 0 , p2 = 0;


    ret = DCCAPI.myCFunction(sBuilder, p2, p1);
    public int myCFunction(StringBuilder sBuilder,int p1, int p2);
```

I tried to change the datatype to char[], String, Byte[]. I got Invalid Memory Access Exception.
Please help!! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you change StringBuilder -> String and try?

Comment: As i mentioned above, i got java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved this problem using PointerByReference.

```
PointerByReference pParam1 = new PointerByReference();
ret = DCCAPI.myCFunction( pParam1, p2, p1);

and then i retrieve the string ;
Pointer ptrParam1 = pParam1.getPointer();
String sTemp = ptrParam1.getString(0);
```

Thanks all....

Answer (score 0):

You can also just pass in a char array and then convert that back to a string inside Java. E.g:

```
char[] buffer = new char[255];
ret = DCCAPI.myCFunction(buffer, p2, p1);
String someString = new String(buffer);
```

One thing to note is that if you don't get the length of the string returned back to you from the C function then you might need to trim nulls from the end of the string. E.g. you'll get back `"abcdef\0\0\0..."`.